# Proof of $(A^TA)^{−1}A^T b=\operatorname{argmin}_x\|Ax-b\|_2$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

What is the proof of the following equation?

$$(A^TA)^{−1}A^T b=\operatorname*{argmin}_x\|Ax-b\|_2$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You assume of course that $A$ has full column rank?

Comment: Thank you, it is first time i use this stackexchange, i am sorry

Comment: See [the proof on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Least-squares_minimization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can decompose $$b = Ax + (b - Ax).\tag 1 $$ pick the $x$ so that $b - Ax$ is orthogonal to $Ax$ that is $$x^TA^T(b - Ax) = 0 $$ a solution is $$x_0 = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb\text{ and } (b-Ax_0) \perp Ax \text{ for any } x .\tag 2$$

to verify the second claim, compute  $(Ax)^T(b-Ax_0) = x^T(A^Tb- A^TAx_0) = x^T(A^Tb - A^T b) = 0.$

we also have  $$b - Ax  = (Ax_0-Ax) +(b-Ax_0) \tag 3  $$

now the phythagoras theorem for a right angle triangle made up of $A(x-x_0), (-Ax_0)$ and the hypotenuse $b- Ax$ shows that 
$$ |b-Ax|^2 \ge |b-Ax_0|^2 \text{ for all } x.$$ therefore $|b-Ax|$ achieves it minimum at $x = x_0.$

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you please explain with more detail. More steps if you can.

Comment: if you can be specific and tell me where you are having trouble with the answer, i can try to explain. is there anything in what i wrote that is not clear to you? you just project $b$ onto column space of $A.$ use the right angle triangle geometry

Comment: Second and third steps are not clear, how it evolved from first step to second one i didn't understand. maybe i don't know some rules so i couldn't understand clearly.

Comment: @GirginSoft, i have edited a little bit. see if that helps.

Comment: look more clear thank u